# C# for loop to write line by line

Tags: c#, for-loop, text

I am trying to write one line of text 75 times and increase the number by 1 till it hits the 75 condition. Starting at 2 for a reason. 
Here's the code

```
class WriteTextFile
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string path = "C:\\Users\\Writefile\\test.txt";
        string line;
        int i = 2;

        while (i <= 75 )
        {
            line = "Error_Flag = 'FOR_IMPORT' and location_type =   'Home' and batch_num = " + i + "\n";
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@path, line);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

With this, it just writes one line with 75 at the end. I want it to write all 74 lines with the same thing, only the number goes up every time. Thanks.

Comment: maybe you should move it to next line in the file after writing the first line...It is overwriting on the same line.

Comment: `File.WriteAllText` is overwriting itself

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`System.IO.File.WriteAllText` will overwrite the contents of the file each time.

What you probably should do is use a StreamWriter:

```
using (var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path))
{
    for (var i = 2; i <= 75; i++)
    {
        sw.WriteLine("Error_Flag = 'FOR_IMPORT' and location_type =   'Home' and batch_num = {0}", i);
    }
}
```

This will automatically create the file, write all the lines, and then close it for you when it's done.

Comment: does `sw.WriteLine` convert everything to string automatically?

Comment: Yes. In fact, `WriteLine` works exactly the same as `string.Format` so you can use bracketed arguments like `sw.WriteLine("... and batch_num = {0}", i);`. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Brain was just not working well today. Still isn't!

Answer (score 4):

Don't use File.WriteAllText because this generates a new file every time.

Instead try something like this:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("filename.txt"))
{
    for(int x = 2; x <= 75; x++)
    {
        writer.WriteLine("Error_Flag = 'FOR_IMPORT' and location_type =  'Home' and batch_num = " + x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted...explain your downvote.  This solution would absolutely work for OP and is currently the same as the just edited top rated answer.

Comment: I didn't, but I don't see the point of having two answers that are basically the same. Yours doesn't really add anything.

Comment: @Andrew I agree with you.  However, I wrote this at the same time as you.  I put in a stub answer and then added code, but as you know in the edit screen you don't see other answers so I wouldn't have known you were planning on writing the same thing I was intending on writing.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the file on each new write operation. Consider [**appending**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx) to it.